# How do you change the value of one attribute by changing the value of another? (dependent attributes)

Tags: python, class, oop, python-3.x, python-3.4

When assigning attributes to objects, I often find that I have to change attributes that are dependent upon others, say, light and darkness. Here's an example:

```
class shade:
    def __init__(self, light):
        self.light=light
        self.darkness=100-light

    def __str__(self):
        return (str(self.light) +  ',' + str(self.darkness))



>>> shade1=shade(30,70)
>>> shade1.light
30
>>> shade1.darkness
70
```

Now, while that is cool and all, what I would like is the same process to occur, but within the same object if a change in one attribute occurs. If I reset the property of light, I want darkness to incr/decr accordingly. I can do this with a function if it works to change the property of light, returning the new value of light/darkness, but I'd like a way to do this if I change the property of light simply by re-assigning its value, without the use of functions. Like this:

```
>>> shade1.light=50
>>> shade1.light
50
>>> shade1.darkness
50
```

Comment: First of all. your class wont work. contractor has only one argument, and you put two when you make the class `shade(30,70)`

Comment: I know, it was intentional, the absence of light is darkness this is 100% dependent on the intensity of light, so I thought it be to set the intensity of light and presume the intensity of darkness. It works out fine if you run it by the way.

Comment: His point is it doesn't, the constructor is defined to take one argument but you are passing two.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Define `darkness` as a [property](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property)

```
class shade:
    def __init__(self, light):
        self.light = light

    @property
    def darkness(self):
        return 100 - self.light

    def __str__(self):
        return '{},{}'.format(self.light, self.darkness)
```

Properties outwardly appear as attributes, but internally act as function calls. When you say `s.darkness` it will call the function you've provided for its property.  This allows you to only maintain one variable internally.

If you want to be able to modify it by assigning to darkness, add a `setter` for the property

```
class shade:
    def __init__(self, light):
        self.light = light

    @property
    def darkness(self):
        return 100 - self.light

    @darkness.setter
    def darkness(self, value):
        self.light = 100 - value
```

Thereby *actually* modifying light.  If you've never seen properties before, I'd recommend throwing in some `print()`s to the bodies of the functions so you can see when they are called.

```
>>> s = shade(70)
>>> s.light
70
>>> s.darkness
30
>>> s.light = 10
>>> s.darkness
90
>>> s.darkness = 20
>>> s.light
80
```

Comment: Fantastic! I knew this feature had to exist. Thanks very much Ryan!

Comment: @user2901512 You are welcome.  FYI, in languages without this feature (Java, C++, etc) it would be done by having a private int for light, and accessing both via method calls, like `s.darkness()` and `s.light()`, adding a level of indirection

Comment: Just to nitpick, supplying a non-integer value for `light` (e.g. 'foo', [], None, -999.) will be silently accepted by `__init__()`, and will only trigger an Exception whenever you subsequently access `darkness`, or call `__str__()`. You may want to typecheck `light` inside `__init__()`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Ryan!

Comment: Hey smci, by typecheck, do you mean raising an attribute error any time a non-int is assigned?

Comment: @user2901512 I can't really recommend that, type checking is generally considered to be an anti-pattern in python.  As you've pointed out one would need a check in every set of darkness and light to be consistent.  If you need static types, use a statically typed language.

Comment: @user2901512 if you were to check, then the most correct exception would be a `TypeError`.  But you really probably shouldn't