# Detecting class attribute value change and then changing another class attribute

Tags: python, class, oop

Let's say I have a class called Number

```
class Number():
  def __init__(self,n):
    self.n=n
    self.changed=None
a = Number(8)
print(a.n) #prints 8
a.n=9
print(a.n) #prints 9
```

When the `n` class attribute changes, I want the `changed` class attribute to be changed to `True`.

Comment: changed to what? `changed` attribute should be changed to what?

Comment: Changed to True

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call Python Method on Class Attribute Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48391851/call-python-method-on-class-attribute-change)

Comment: This is an instance attribute, a class attribute is something entirely different.  The answer is to make `n` a `@property`, so that code runs when it is assigned.

Comment: Please [edit] the code in your question and show how you intend to _use_ the `changed` attribute.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you change the value of one attribute by changing the value of another? (dependent attributes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308560/how-do-you-change-the-value-of-one-attribute-by-changing-the-value-of-another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible with proper use of `@propety`

```
class Number():
  def __init__(self,n):
    self._n=n
    self._changed=None

  @property
  def n(self):
      return self._n

  @property
  def changed(self):
      return self._changed

  @n.setter
  def n(self, val):
      # while setting the value of n, change the 'changed' value as well
      self._n = val
      self._changed = True

a = Number(8)
print(a.n) #prints 8
a.n=9
print(a.n) #prints 9
print(a.changed)
```

Returns:

```
8
9
True
```

Comment: You wouldn't need a property for `changed`.

Comment: Added that to keep it consistent with what OP is expecting